# How i can open new client channel inside server handler to other address

Tags: java, netty

I use netty. In may application i process inсoming packets, but i need send parsed packet in other server and should return to the incoming flow of the result of processing the package third-party server; How i can open new connection inside server hadler for send packet to third-party server and read result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would write a client with netty.

Netty client example: http://static.netty.io/3.6/guide/#start.9

You'd need to use the `ClientBootstrap` to set up a new bootstrap, create a pipeline factory, handlers, etc, etc.

In all honestly, that's probably a bit overkill unless you *really* need it to be async, which is sounds like you don't. If it's just a REST service or something similar you need to access, I'd just use a plaid old `HttpUrlConnection` and get what you need synchronously.